# How to handle pure native elements using detox

Tags: react-native, detox

I'm using detox but I need to handle my native login page using detox.

Comment: Can you share some code or give more details about your requirement

Comment: My app is hybrid app, whenever the app launch, I need to interact with pure native app components.

Comment: Are you working with react-native. Can you share more info like which app compnent you need to interact

Comment: Yes, In our app few scenes are in native and few of them are in react native. On App launch, we lands to native screen from that we will navigate to react native screen. I need to navigate from native to react native screen. How can we do these on Detox?

Comment: If you are building react-native cli app, After loading splash screen (Which is native screen) it will automatically load one of the component of react native

Comment: Native screen means which is written in swift(ios). Our main Screen written in swift. basically its an hybrid app.

Comment: As detox native doc says, Detox is built from the ground up to support React Native projects as well as pure native ones.

Comment: @Ajith If you don't understand the question, why do you fill up the comments?

Answer (score 2):

Detox supports native elements. In order to interact with them, you need to set an [`accessibilityIdentifier`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiaccessibilityidentification/1623132-accessibilityidentifier?language=objc) to the elements you want to interact with, and then the normal `by.id()` API will work as expected.

Comment: Do you know what to set in native Android for getting  it in by.id() in the RN side?

Comment: On Android, the test-ID - that is the input for by.id(), is set as the view's main tag: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View#setTag(java.lang.Object). Does that help?

Comment: @d4vidi ,Yes thank you, do i need to set it like this in the native:  button.setTag("barak") and get the "barak" in by.id('barak'). because i tried it and it didn't work.

Comment: @Leo Natan can you please add example with setTag for native android in the answer. Toda Achi ;)

Comment: I don't feel comfortable adding Android. Feel free to edit the answer.

Comment: Yes, either that or you apply the tag in advance in the view's xml. Inspect your layout hierarchy with Android studio to make sure the tag is indeed properly placed! Here are examples to how we apply both approaches in Detox' self-test app, which runs tests over pure-native layouts in some cases: https://github.com/wix/Detox/blob/b73a173266001f66d53f01bfc0d6d710feec5045/detox/test/android/app/src/main/java/com/example/DoubleTapsTextViewManager.java#L35, https://github.com/wix/Detox/blob/86a5608956bd0fae73b9180c1cbc59af1de40a74/detox/test/android/app/src/main/res/layout/animation_test.xml#L14